# Spring boot large file upload and download support

Tags: spring-boot, large-files

I have a spring boot web application which will handle large file (max size of 5g) upload and then save it to s3. The request and response may last for a long time.

So what is the best practice to handle the upload and download like this? How to make a good performance to prevent my server down when download or upload large files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **multipart/form-data**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/agency/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> createAgency(
            @RequestParam(value = "username", required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(value = "pic1", required = true)MultipartFile pic1File,
            MultipartHttpServletRequest request, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        List<String> requestKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> originalFileName=new ArrayList<String>();

        request.getFileNames().forEachRemaining(requestKeys::add);
        for(String multipartFile:requestKeys) {
            originalFileName.add(request.getFile(multipartFile).getOriginalFilename());
        }
        storageService.store(pic1File);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(originalFileName, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a frontend, all of them used as a restful api.

Comment: i will modify the answer  for restful API

Comment: MultiPartFile javadocs says *A representation of an uploaded file received in a multipart request. 

The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk. In either case, the user is responsible for copying file contents to a session-level or persistent store as and if desired. The temporary storage will be cleared at the end of request processing*

So it means file is uploaded first in memory, I think the requirement is to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Posting in case someone finds this useful in the future. This works with a REST controller as of Spring Boot 2.4.2.

Class annotations:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
```

Method declaration:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/file-upload/{depot}/{fileName}", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
        public ResponseEntity<String> fileUpload(
                @PathVariable(name = "depot") String depot,
                @PathVariable(name = "fileName") String fileName,
                InputStream inputStream,
                HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
```

The above is the Spring Boot configuration for a REST Controller that worked for me for large file upload. The key was adding InputStream inputStream directly.

Comment: How large of a file were you generally working with? I have concerns that Spring might still try to put the entirety of the file in memory, which for multi-gigabyte files would blow out my server memory allocation.